# Design GUI which can run command line queries dependent on user input

Tags: python, user-interface, command-line

How can I create a GUI, which can run command line queries dependent on user input in GUI. For example if the user inputs a path in the  path textfield, the command prompt should be run all python scripts in that path. Which programming language would you suggest me? And is there some kind of window GUI builder that can help me out?

Comment: Only the last line of this question is valid under S.O. guidelines.

Comment: For gui you may use tkinter, PySide, easy gui etc.

Comment: As for language, you may use any language to do this